# BlueZ Gatt server app bryy using Dbus

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, dbus, bluez

I am very new to Bluez and I want to create some custom profile (GATT server) with one service and 2 Characteristics by using Bluez5.49 version.

I don't know how to start. I want to write this as a C application via Dbus. I don't want to use any command line operation for advertise.

I have doubt like if I advertise my device by using Dbus how I know whether I got scan request from Master (Central device). Which Dbus method is used to read the event of the BLE? How to proceed further?

Comment: This is quite broad ... Maybe you could have a look at the [BlueZ API reference](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc), the examples (e.g. _test/example-advertisement_) and the tools provided with BlueZ, and come back with more specific questions? The examples are in python but they should work as D-Bus API examples.  Also the tools included in source are in C (including e.g. a GATT server).

Comment: Hi , 
I have advertise my device via command or application and How to i know central device is give scan response to my device and How to find that event ? , So i need one event to poll the status of BLE and their response . That's my doubt .